# Serialize protobuf message to bytes in Python results in Exit code 137

Tags: python, serialization, byte, protocol-buffers

I've a problem with serializing my protobuf message to bytes. The message is quite big and consists of multiple key value maps. I want to serialize the message to bytes and save it to a file. I've tried all three of the following methods to serialize my protobuf message `converted_content`

```
converted_string = converted_content.SerializeToString()
converted_bytes = converted_content.__bytes__() 
converted_bytes = bytes(converted_content)
```

but for all of them I end up with exit code 137 and no bytes :(

```
Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

I don't know what the issue can be. I'm able to serialize my message to JSON like this

```
converted_content.to_json()
```

I'm using Python 3.7.9 and the Protobuf message classes in Python are generated using betterproto.

What can the problem be and how can I solve it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, was an issue on my end. A variable was incorrectly set to integer but the model defined it as a datetime type. Weird that it passed initialization